# ¿Cuál es el error al configurar el carrusel de bootstrap con php?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, php7, carrusel

vuelvo para ver si me podrían ayudar con un pequeño problema que estoy teniendo al crear un carrusel (Con bootstrap y php para traer la información de mi bd) en mi web, el problema es el siguiente:

Que yo al darle click a cualquiera de las publicaciones, SOLO SE MUEVE EL PRIMERO. (ahí identifique en la foto cual sería el primero)No importa si le doy al segundo para que me muestre las fotos o al tercero, si o si, solo se mueve el primero, los otros no hacen nada (Pero si mueve las fotos en modo automático)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto también mi codigo de php:

```
   <div class="body_color_all">
        <!-- Start post-content Area -->
        <?php

   $conexion = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pet_shop ORDER BY id DESC");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($conexion)>0){

      while($result_shop=mysqli_fetch_array($conexion)){

    $id_pet_shop = $result_shop['id'];

    ?>

     <section class="pet_Shopping"> 

      <div class="date_time_public">
        <p>Publicación realizada el: <?=fecha($result_shop['date_time'])?>&nbsp;<span class="lnr 
           lnr-calendar-full"></span></p>
     </div>
    
<div class="texto_shop">
    <h2><?=$result_shop['titulo']?></h2>
                                    
    <p><?=$result_shop['contenido']?><p>
</div>

<div class="img_pet_shop_contenedor">                       
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php
          $controle_ativo = 2;      
          $controle_num_slide = 1;
            if($controle_ativo == 2){ ?>
            
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              
              <?php
              $controle_ativo = 1;
            }else{ ?>
            
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $controle_num_slide; ?>"></li>
              
              <?php
              $controle_num_slide++;
            }
        ?>                      
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php
          $controle_ativo = 2;                      
            if($controle_ativo == 2){ ?>
            
              <div class="item active">
                <img loading="lazy" class="img_carru" src="admin/PET_SHOP/<?php echo $result_shop['img_prod']; ?>" >
              </div>
              
              <?php
              $controle_ativo = 1;
              
            }
            
            $cargar_fotos = "SELECT * FROM pet_shop_2 WHERE id_shop = '$id_pet_shop'";
            $cargando = mysqli_query($mysqli,$cargar_fotos);
            
            if(mysqli_num_rows($cargando)>0){

              while($traer_fotos2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cargando)){
            
            ?>
              <div class="item">
                <img loading="lazy" class="img_carru" src="admin/PET_SHOP/<?php echo 
    $traer_fotos2['img2']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $traer_fotos2['id_shop']; ?>">
              </div> 
              
              <?php
            }
          }
        
        ?>                  
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data- 
        slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data- 
        slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
      </div>

    </section>

   <?php
        }
    }   
  ?>
  </div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Carousel/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Estás creando un carrusel para cada foto, todos con mismo ID y todos los _data-target_ usan ese ID, es normal que solo "funcione" con uno, porque el identificador debe ser único.

Comment: Eso me supuse, buscando en Internet vi eso, pero más bien mi pregunta sería ¿Cómo podría hacer para darles un id único a cada carrusel o contenedor? Ya que podrían ser varias publicaciones

Comment: @AnthonyMelchor esa ya es una cuestión totalmente diferente. Lo que puedes hacer es crear un contador, e ir sumándolo dentro de las etiquetas id en cada bucle. Por ejemplo, tienes el contador `$i +=1` y luego en tu id pondrías `id="carousel<?php $i ?>"`